# Java regex negation

Tags: java, regex

I have found [in the java api for Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) the negation of characters using `[^abc] - Any character except a, b, or c (negation)`

The opposite is `[abc] - a, b, or c (simple class)`

Now, I want to combine those both like:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[set^k]*", "ktest")); // returns true
```

But I want something like:

Allow all `t's`, `e's` and `s's`, but refuse all `k's` in the String.

Thank you for your help!

Kind regards

Comment: with `[set^k]` you are allowing `s` `e` `t` `^` and `k` to occur. If you only want `s` `e` `t` without `k` than stick to `[abc]` cause it already excludes `k`

Answer (score 1):

To allow `s`, `e` and `t` but disallow `k`, just use `[set]`.  Anything that's not explicitly listed will be disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Pattern.matches("[setk&&[^k]]*", "testttteeeskss"); // false
```

Which is like match `s,e,t,k` but negate `k`. Effectively it is same `[set]`.